# Rest Api PUT method not receiving values

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, rest, put

I have this code in Ajax/Jquery, where I am trying to request a PUT method to my API. In my code I am trying to send the data that has been updated in my text fields. This data should be received by the API and send it to the Model it should be used to update a records in my database based on the ID recived. For some reason, my REST API in the controller is not receiving the values from my text fields.

Code where I am sending the data:

```
$("#edit").on("click", function() {
     var updatedData ={ question: $('#questionField').val(),
                        image: $('#imageField').val(),
                        answer1: $('#answer1Field').val(),
                        answer2: $('#answer2Field').val(),
                        answer3: $('#answer3Field').val(),
                        answer4: $('#answer4Field').val(),
                         };
      $.ajax({
              url : '../admincontroller/getdatabasedata/', 
              type: 'PUT',
              dataType: 'json', 
              data: updatedData,

              success: function(updatedQuestion)
              {
                JSON.stringify(updatedQuestion);
                if(updatedQuestion.ok == 1) {
                  alert("Succesfully edited");
                }
                else{
                  alert(updatedQuestion.ok);
                }
              }
          });
    return false; 
  });
```

Code for my REST API where data should be received:

```
    else if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'PUT' )
            {
                    $id = $this->input->post('idField');
                    $question = $this->input->post('questionField');
                    $image = $this->input->post('imageField');
                    $answer1 = $this->input->post('answer1Field');
                    $answer2 = $this->input->post('answer2Field');
                    $answer3 = $this->input->post('answer3Field');
                    $answer4 = $this->input->post('answer4Field');

if($question != '' && $image != '' && $answer1 != '' && $answer2 != '' && $answer3 != '' && $answer4 != ''){
                        $this->adminmodel->updateQuestion($id,$question,$image,$answer1,$answer2,$answer3,$answer4);
                        echo json_encode(array('ok' => 1));
                    }
                    else{
                        echo json_encode(array('ok' => $question));
                    }   

            }
```

At the moment I am trying to alert to see if the data is passed, but I just get NULL.  Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: I know thats not what you asked for, but as it seems you are going in a very wrong direction if you want to create a REST API. You should not use "PUT" and more likely "POST", because you do not want to create or update an entity to its URI, what PUT should be used for! PUT also has do be idempotent, which your action seems not to be. Also the URI "getdatabasedata" is not RESTful at all. There should be no verbs in the URI. In REST the verbs are the HTTP method you can put on any entity or it respective URI, so the URI should be "/databasedata/". See e.g. http://www.restapitutorial.com

Answer (score 0):

I think the data needs to be a String. Objects are converted to querystrings which is what you are seeing here.

data: JSON.stringify(updatedData)  instead of updatedData

Comment: And how should I get it on the other side in my REST api?

Answer (score 0):

Follow similar data contract structure and parameter names. If you are using primitive types pass them in url or mark the primitive type of sent in body in the api function. 
Use JSON.stringify(object) as data for Ajax call for sending objects.
Make sure http verbs are enabled on server.